# Things are becoming slow while making an android like drawer using HTML , CSS , vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, performance

What I am trying to do is make a drawer where drawer can be opened with left swipe from the edge and can be closed from right swipe from anywhere, if swipe is more than 150px.

I have achieved everything, however, the drawer becomes laggy and ultimately the browser freezes. The code for the following is as below.

```js
let drawer = document.getElementsByClassName('drawer')[0];

function openDrawer(start) {
  document.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
    let end = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    if ((end > start) && ((end - start) > 150)) {
      drawer.classList.add('tra')
      drawer.style.transform = `translateX(0px)`;
    }
  });
}

function closeDrawer(start) {
  document.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
    let end = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    if ((end < start) && ((start - end) > 150)) {
      drawer.classList.add('tra')
      drawer.style.transform = `translateX(-104%)`;
    }
  });
}

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
  drawer.classList.remove('tra')
  let start = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  if (start < 50) {
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function() {
      let change = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
      let drawerWidth = drawer.offsetWidth;
      let move = change - drawerWidth;
      let min = 0;
      let max = -drawerWidth;
      if (move < max) {
        move = max;
      }
      if (move > min) {
        move = min;
      }
      drawer.style.transform = `translateX(${move}px)`;
      document.addEventListener('touchmove', function() {
        document.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
          if (change >= drawerWidth / 2) {
            drawer.classList.add('tra');
            drawer.style.transform = `translateX(0%)`;
          } else {
            drawer.classList.add('tra');
            drawer.style.transform = `translateX(-104%)`;
          }
        });
      })
    })
    openDrawer(start)
  } else {
    closeDrawer(start)
  }
}, 500);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.drawer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  background: hotpink;
  transform: translateX(-104%);
}

.tra {
  transition: 500ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="drawer" id="drawer">

</div>
```

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0xre4uo5/5/

Comment: You're binding more and more event listeners in the `openDrawer(start)` and `closeDrawer(start)` functions

Comment: so any workaround ?

Comment: I think you need to remove the previously event listeners in the `touchend` event - Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/robm41gz/1/) maybe?

Comment: yeah you _really_ need to clean up your events. Or listen for start events at the document level and only have it kick in when event.target is your "drawer", and the same for end events (rather than constantly adding/removing event listeners).